# Junit class - Failed to load ApplicationContext, base Test class

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

Trying to build an abandoned project from googlecode. The first step is to get a build from the close to untouched source. The entire source repo is at https://github.com/tromberg/hibernate-generic-dao

The project has a main "parent" project, and every module is a child of it, with it's own `pom.xml`

All the tests inherit from a child module called test-base, which has the annotations:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:jUnit-applicationContext.xml" })
public abstract class BaseTest extends PersistableTestDataModel {
```

When i import this project in intellij, it says the file `jUnit-applicationContext.xml` has no Application Context.

one failing test is https://github.com/tromberg/hibernate-generic-dao/blob/master/search/src/test/java/junit/googlecode/genericdao/search/JPAAnnotationMetadataTest.java

```
public class JPAAnnotationMetadataTest extends BaseTest {
```

When i try to build with a simple `mvn verify` or run any tests from intellij (even manually adding an Application Context with that very same file using type Spring there) I get:

```
ERROR   2019-08-09 15:21:37.341 org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance()
        Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@68034211] to prepare test instance [junit.googlecode.genericdao.search.JPAAnnotationMetadataTest@4f74980d]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
```

Tried adding the context to each test, but not exactly sure where it should live here. Anyone familiar with this testing pattern?

Comment: Does it fail from the command line `mvn verify` or `mvn test` or is it specific to IntelliJ IDEA? If it's not IntelliJ IDEA specific you may want to remove the corresponding tag from your question.

Comment: @CrazyCoder good point. removing the tag. I put it there in case anyone had any insight because it complains about the lack of application context on the application context itself.